# Map between rings generated by sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Say we have a unital commutative ring (or a field). Let $S$ be subset of that ring and let $K=\mathbb{Z}[\{S\}]$ be the ring generated by $S$. Now let $S^{'} \subseteq S$ and $K^{'}=\mathbb{Z}[\{S^{'}\}]$ be the ring generated by $S^{'}$. Define $f:K \to K^{'}$ to be the algebraic extension of the rule which sends $x \in S$ to itself if $s \in S^{'}$ and to $0$ otherwise. Is such map always a ring homomorphism? That it preserves addition, multiplication and the identity is true by the definition of $f$, I guess. The only thing I am not completely sure about is if it well-define (I think it is). Is there a way of showing this (that it is always a ring homomorphism) by the means of some universal property?

Comment: Wait, what is $\Bbb Z[\{S\}]$ anyway? The set of all formal integer-linear combinations of finite products (formed in the given unnamed ring) of elements of $S$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, that's him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the given ring be $\Bbb F_5=\{0,1,a,a^2,a^3\}$, $S=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}$, $S'=\{1,a^2\}$. Then you want $f(c_1\cdot 1+c_2\cdot a+c_3\cdot a^2+c_4\cdot a^3)=c_1\cdot 1+c_3\cdot a^2$, but that makes
$$f((1\cdot a)(1\cdot a))=f(1\cdot a^2)=1\ne 0=f(1\cdot a)\cdot f(1\cdot a).$$